# Access 2007 query to not cut-off records if one particular join doesn't exist

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I feel a bit stupid for asking this, because I'm sure there is a simple other type of join I should be using, however, I can't seem to find the answer, so I'm hoping one of you can point me in the  right direction.

I have a big query in Access 2007 that pulls in records, but in some cases, I can't use an INNER JOIN on some tables, because linking records may not exist, so the main record rightly drops off. I can get round this problem by using IIF statements, checking if an entry exists first, but this makes the query terribly slow. I simplify the scenario below. Many thanks in advance:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.